# ADB doesn't work on debian

Tags: android, debian, port, adb, x86-64

I'm using a debian wheezy amd64, I don't manage to start `ADB`. I know there are several threads on that subjects but none of those trials didn't work out.

I always have same result :

```
`---> sudo ./adb start-server
<br> 
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
<br>
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
<br>
ADB server didn't ACK
<br>
* failed to start daemon *`
```

There is nothing running on port 5037. I checked with `netstat -a` Neither any adb process by `ps aux | grep adb`

The pass is well exported. I have the good rights on adb file. I don't know what to do any more.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if it needs those libraries, but do you have ia32-libs installed?

Comment: I might need them, the libs are already instaled.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I was just making sure you already had them. Just in case.

Comment: More information on the problem can be found out using strace to run the application. As root: strace ./adb start-server

Comment: Thank you, I know about this command, unfortunately I'm not so great in Linux Administration to understand what the result mean. There really is a tone of information.

Comment: @brasov777: I develop with Eclipse/android on AMD64/sid. I don't remember having installed anything else than ADT. What does `adb shell` return ?

Comment: This is bug in current version of adb in Debian package, see http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=715238

Answer (score 1):

If you only need ADB, you can give a try to the Debian package [`adb`](http://packages.debian.org/adb) (former android-tools-adb).

The main advantage is that this ADB is compiled from sources for your running platform (amd64, I suppose). So, you won't have any "32 bits library" problem.